# Import contacts from phone to list in my app in android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

In my app, I wanted to enable user to display contacts from their phone. I used this [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/) to open my phone contacts from the app. But now I want to make a list of contacts in my app, by copying all the contacts from the phone. What would be the best way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I already know how to display the contacts, but i do not know how to save them to sqlite db. I am a beginner so any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150316083304/http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-contacts-content-provider-retrieving-and-listing-contacts-in-listview-example/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

Add **Function:**

```
private List<Person> getContactList(){
        ArrayList<Person> contactList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        };
        String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "='1'";
        Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);


        if (contacts.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while(contacts.moveToNext()) {
                Person aContact = new Person();
                int idFieldColumnIndex = 0;
                int nameFieldColumnIndex = 0;
                int numberFieldColumnIndex = 0;

                String contactId = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                nameFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (nameFieldColumnIndex > -1)
                {
                    aContact.setName(contacts.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex));
                }

                PROJECTION = new String[] {Phone.NUMBER};
                final Cursor phone = managedQuery(Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
                if(phone.moveToFirst()) {
                    while(!phone.isAfterLast())
                    {
                        numberFieldColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                        if (numberFieldColumnIndex > -1)
                        {
                            aContact.setPhoneNum(phone.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex));
                            phone.moveToNext();
                            TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
                            mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                            if (!mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number().contains(aContact.getPhoneNum()))
                            {
                                contactList.add(aContact);  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                phone.close();
            }

            contacts.close();
        }

        return contactList;
    }
```

**Person.java** :

```
public class Person {
    String myName = "";
    String myNumber = "";

    public String getName() {
        return myName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        myName = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNum() {
        return myNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNum(String number) {
        myNumber = number;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I just tried Umer's solution and it worked. I will also try this one, it seems even more compact. Thanks again

Comment: @Kemo, most welcome. :)